# How can I access Desktop if it says "-bash: cd: /home/username/Desktop: No such file or directory"?

Tags: command-line

I tried `cd /home/username/Desktop` but still didn't work. And when I enter `ls` it shows the "practice" folder I created, not the desktop.

[image: it doesn't show the desktop directory]

Comment: I have never used the Windows Subsystem for Linux, so I don't know if it creates the typical home folders structure. But if you need a Desktop folder, you can run `mkdir -p /home/jared/Desktop` to create it by yourself.

Comment: but how can I access the Desktop itself and the files in the Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible reasons for there not being a Desktop (or any of the other directories).

1. You installed a server version. Servers tend to not have a desktop so also do not have a directory linking to a Desktop. If this is the case, and you want a desktop, you can install a desktop. The 2 most used:

   - GNOME: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`
   - KDE `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`
2. You installed WSL (Windows subsystem layer; a tool where you can use Ubuntu from within Windows). That one does not have a desktop do will also not have those directories.

- These 2 you login from a prompt not from a graphical login.

3. You do have a desktop and created the user manually without creating a `/home/$USER` and created `jared` yourself or deleted the contents of `/home/jared`. In that case feel free to do a

   ```
   cd /home/jared && mkdir Desktop Music Documents Downloads Templates Videos
   ```

   But I doubt this ... those directories are automatically re-created as soon as you login into the system from a graphical login.

Comment: Related: [Who is creating Documents/Video/Pictures/etc. in home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268721/380915)